# UWP C#: Adding MapPolygon to MapControl

Tags: c#, google-maps, uwp

I am trying to add a polygon to my map by using the following code example (retrieved from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/display-poi#add-a-shape):

```
public void HighlightArea() {

double centerLatitude = myMap.Center.Position.Latitude;
double centerLongitude = myMap.Center.Position.Longitude;

var mapPolygon = new MapPolygon
{
    Path = new Geopath(new List<BasicGeoposition> {
                new BasicGeoposition() {Latitude=centerLatitude+0.0005, Longitude=centerLongitude-0.001 },
                new BasicGeoposition() {Latitude=centerLatitude-0.0005, Longitude=centerLongitude-0.001 },
                new BasicGeoposition() {Latitude=centerLatitude-0.0005, Longitude=centerLongitude+0.001 },
                new BasicGeoposition() {Latitude=centerLatitude+0.0005, Longitude=centerLongitude+0.001 },
            }),
    ZIndex = 1,
    FillColor = Colors.Red,
    StrokeColor = Colors.Blue,
    StrokeThickness = 3,
    StrokeDashed = false,
};

// Add MapPolygon to a layer on the map control.
var MyHighlights = new List<MapElement>();

MyHighlights.Add(mapPolygon);

var HighlightsLayer = new MapElementsLayer
{
    ZIndex = 1,
    MapElements = MyHighlights
};

myMap.Layers.Add(HighlightsLayer);
```

}

The polygon is shown on the map initially, but it disappears within 2 seconds from when it appeared (it fades away). I have successfully added a MapPolyline that sticks to the map by using an example I retrieved from the same link, which is why I cannot understand why the MapPolygon will not stick.

What may cause the polygon to fade away?

Comment: The sample worked for me. Please tell me your project platform version and your OS build version? I suggested that you could first try the official [MapControl](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MapControl) sample to see if it will work.

Comment: I am targeting Windows 10, version 1803 (10.0; Build 17134) @XavierXie-MSFT

Comment: Have you tried to run the official [MapControl](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MapControl) sample to see if it will work on your side?